# How to set CSS properties with JQuery with slow motion?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to get fading effect in JQuery using `.css()`. I'm able to do this with the statement:

```
$("p").fadeTo("slow", 0.0);
```

A similar effect I'm able to get with the statement:

```
$("p").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

When using `fadeTo()`, I am able to specify the timing (like "slow", "fast", milliseconds) but I don't know how to specify the timing with `.css()`

Please let me know how can I achieve this. I am comfortable with CSS, I want to achieve this with `.css()`

Comment: You'll need to create a css animation, `$.css()` just sets the style. If you want to animate something, use [`$.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of `$.css()` - or even better a dedicated animation library such as [velocityjs](http://velocityjs.org/)

Comment: `$.css()` applies css properties only you can use `animate` if you donot want to use `fadeTo`

Comment: have look to my answer ...that is working fine...it will give you feel of hiding element

Comment: `visibility` isn't an animatable property. If you wish to use CSS animation, you need to animate `opacity`. You could set in CSS a class using transition for opacity and just add this class from jQuery. Or set both the transition and opacity using `css()` method. See e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/5b9dog9b/

Comment: check my updated answer you just need this     $("#paragraph").hide("slow");
    $("#paragraph").show("slow");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hide

```
$("p").fadeOut(1000); // This will hide the p element with an animation of 1 sec duration
```

For show

```
$("p").fadeIn(1000);
```

if you want use css with this, then for show

```
 $('p').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000); // show p
```

For hide

```
$('p').css({opacity: 1, visibility: "hidden"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000); // hide p
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try `show` and `hide` function that acheive same result do not need of seting visiblity property

```
$("#paragraph").hide("slow");
$("#paragraph").show("slow");
```

---

you can aslo try out this option if you just want to hide element with effect , then try this oud

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#p1").slideUp(2000);
    });
});


<p id="p1">Hide me !!</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

this one just hide out element form visibility point of view , but element stays in your DOM.

---

you can do like this , you use animate to decrease opacity of element than in complete call back just set visiblity to hidden.

```
<p id="hidep">
 data
  dfg;ljdfsgj
  sfdgfdsgdsfg
  fdsgdfs
</p>
```

---

```
 $( "#hidep" ).animate({
  opacity: 0.1
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function() {
      $( this ).css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  });
```

check working demo at jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7a8nes56/1/

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to do this.  Following are 3 examples in 1 snippet so you can see them animate together visually.

1. jQuery only using `.animate()`
2. CSS only using `css-animate` and keyframes
3. CSS `transition` with the aid of jQuery.

Personally I prefer doing this with CSS alone, but since you asked for jQuery I provided a couple ways you can do this.

**Browser support for CSS versions:**

https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20animation

https://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20transition

**To achieve your 'slow motion':**

In these cases you'll just increase the duration:

1. jQuery `animate()` takes a number or string. Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The default duration is 400 milliseconds. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. [Source](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
2. `css-animate` takes a duration in seconds as the second argument after the name of the animation. This is the `animation-duration` property when not using shorthand. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).
3. `transition` takes a duration in seconds as the second argument after the property/properties being transitioned.  This is the `transition-duration` property when not using shorthand. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

```js
$(function() {
    // Using .animate() only:
    $('.jquery-animate').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 5000);
    
    // Using jQuery to apply CSS transition by adding a class on load:
    $('.css-transition-with-jquery').addClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
/* CSS Animate method */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.css-animate {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s ; 
  -moz-animation:    fadeIn 5s ; 
  -o-animation:      fadeIn 5s ; 
  animation:         fadeIn 5s ; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
}

/* CSS and jQuery Method */
.css-transition-with-jquery {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;

}
.css-transition-with-jquery.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="jquery-animate">
<strong>jQuery only with .animate()</strong>. Aliquam fringilla lacus erat, in tempus lorem egestas sagittis. Suspendisse in maximus est. Ut elementum ultricies mi, at dictum enim ullamcorper vel. Suspendisse sodales feugiat leo, vel sollicitudin felis eleifend quis. Nullam venenatis viverra ultricies. Nulla vel lorem sem. Praesent vestibulum maximus elit, non consectetur urna eleifend eu. Donec vel feugiat ex.
</p>

<hr/>

<p class="css-animate">
<strong>CSS only using css-animate.</strong> Aliquam fringilla lacus erat, in tempus lorem egestas sagittis. Suspendisse in maximus est. Ut elementum ultricies mi, at dictum enim ullamcorper vel. Suspendisse sodales feugiat leo, vel sollicitudin felis eleifend quis. Nullam venenatis viverra ultricies. Nulla vel lorem sem. Praesent vestibulum maximus elit, non consectetur urna eleifend eu. Donec vel feugiat ex.
</p>

<hr/>

<p class="css-transition-with-jquery">
<strong>CSS transition with jQuery</strong> Aliquam fringilla lacus erat, in tempus lorem egestas sagittis. Suspendisse in maximus est. Ut elementum ultricies mi, at dictum enim ullamcorper vel. Suspendisse sodales feugiat leo, vel sollicitudin felis eleifend quis. Nullam venenatis viverra ultricies. Nulla vel lorem sem. Praesent vestibulum maximus elit, non consectetur urna eleifend eu. Donec vel feugiat ex.
</p>
```